# How to identify 404 URL in XML?

Tags: xml, http-status-code-404

I'm making XML file which should import data to my website from another system. The problem is **URL** through which *txt file should be downloaded. Is there any way to check if given URL returns 404 HTTP status?

```
<source>
  <id>1</id>                              
  <url>http://www.destination.com/sources/box.txt</url>
  <name>Box</name>
</source>
```

Comment: The response status for a normal response status is 200 OK.  400 one of the failure response status.

Comment: Yes I know - 404 returns "not found".